# Parallel Processing with Starting New Task - front end screen timeout

Tags: parallel-processing, abap

I am running an ABAP program to work with a huge amount of data. The SAP documentation gives the information that I should use 
Remote Function Modules with the addition STARTING NEW TASK to process the data.

So my program first selects all the data, breaks the data into packages and calls a function module with a package of data for further processing.

So that's my pseudo code:

```
Select KEYFIELD from MYSAP_TABLE into table KEY_TABLE package size 500.

 append KEY_TABLE to ALL_KEYS_TABLE.

Endselect.


Loop at ALL_KEYS_TABLE assigning <fs_table> .

  call function 'Z_MASS_PROCESSING'
     starting new TASK 'TEST' destination in group default
       exporting
           IT_DATA = <fs_table> .

Endloop .
```

But I am surprised to see that I am using Dialog Processes instead of Background Process for the call of my function module.

So now I encountered the problem that one of my Dialog Processes were killed after 60 Minutes because of Timeout.

For me, it seems that STARTING NEW TASK is not the right solution for parallel processing of mass data.

What will be the alternative?

Comment: Did you try the refresh screen after each parallel process finished? Thus, the screen will not be locked all the processing time.

Comment: There is a dedicated framework for parallel processing (FPP) from SAP which should be available in an ERP-System. I do not know if it is good documented though. Try to search for the function module `BANK_MAP_PP_START` in your system.

Comment: Why not submit your program through the FMs that manage background jobs, like JOB_OPEN, JOB_SUBMIT, JOB_CLOSE? Furthermore, if your NW stack is on top of the HANA DB you could use AMDP (ABAP Managed Database Procedure) class and push your data to the database level for processing. Not sure if maybe, at this point, AMDP is supported for databases other than SAP HANA.

Comment: @Jagger thanks for the hint of FPP. I know the framework but I think that it is a little bit oversized for my requirement. But the advantage is that the parallel processes are running in background processes and not dialog processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, best way for parallel processing in SAP is Bank Parallel Processing framework as Jagger mentioned. Unfortunently its rarerly mentioned in any resource and its not documented well.
Actually, best documentation I found was in this book

https://www.sap-press.com/abap-performance-tuning_2092/

Yes, it's tricky. It costed me about 5 or 6 days to force it going. But results were good.

All stuff is situated in package `BANK_PP_JOBCTRL` and you can use its name for googling.

Main idea there is to divide all your work into steps (simplified):

1. Preparation
2. Parallel processing

   2.1. Processing preparation

   2.2. Processing
   (Actually there are more steps there)

First step is not paralleized. Here you should prepare all you data for parallel processing and devide it into 'piece' which will be processed in parallel. 
Content of pieces, in turn, can be ID or preloaded data as well.
After that, you can run step 2 in parallel processing. 
Great benefit of all this is that error in one piece of parallel work won't lead to crash of all your processing. 
I recomend you check demo in function group `BANK_API_PP_DEMO`

Comment: well that's true. you hardly find any documentation about this framework

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, thats not an easy topic that is handled with a few lines of codes. The general steps you have to conduct in a thoughtful way to gain the desired benefit is:

1) Get free work processes available for parallel processing

2) Slice your data in packages to be processed

3) Call an RFC enabled function module asynchronously for each package with the available work processes. Handle waiting for free work processes, if packages > available processes

4) Receive your results asynchronously

5) Wait till everything is processed and merge the data together again and assure that every package was handled properly

Although it is bad practice to just post links, the code is very long and would make this answer very messy, therfore take a look at the following links:

[Example1-aRFC](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/Easily%20implement%20parallel%20processing%20in%20online%20and%20batch%20processing?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com)

[Example2-aRFC](http://www.teamabap.com/2014/05/parallel-processing-in-abap.html)

[Example3-aRFC](http://web.archive.org/web/20141119132409/http://sapignite.com:80/learn-parallel-processing-in-abap/)

Other RFC variants (e.g. qRFC, tRFC etc.) can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/48/99b53cee2b73e7e10000000a42189b/content.htm) with short description but sadly cannot give you further insight on them.

EDIT:

[Regarding process type of aRFC:](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/c4/3a7f1f505211d189550000e829fbbd/content.htm)

> In parallel processing, a job step is started as usual in a background
>   processing work process. (...)While the job itself runs in a
>   background process, the parallel processing tasks that it starts run
>   in dialog work processes. Such dialog work processes may be located on
>   any SAP server.

The server is specified with the GROUP (default: parallel_generators) see transaction RZ12 and can have its own ressources just for parallel processing. If your process times out, you have to slice your packages differently in size.

Comment: There is also function module SPTA_PARA_PROCESS_START_2 available, which is a small framework for aRFC. It can help you with some of the technical hurdles, in contrast to develop everything by yourself. You can check demo report SPTA_PARA_DEMO_1 or search web for function module to get more examples.

Comment: @TapioReisinger thanks, that sounds very interesting. I will have a look at the demo report

Comment: @futu I hat a look at the examples but when I understand all the docs right, the remote function modules will run in dialog work processes. Is my understanding right?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer I edited the answer regarding the process type

Answer (score 2):

To implement parallel processing, you need to do a bit more than just add that clause. The information is contained in [this help topic](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7bfe8cdcfbb040dcb6702dada8c3e2f0/7.5.8/en-US/4d909309eba36e73e10000000a15822b.html). A lot of design effort needs to be devoted to ensure that the communication and result merging overhead of the parallel processing does not negate the performance advantage gained by the parallel processing in the first place and that referential integrity of the data is maintained even when some of the parallel tasks fail. Do not under-estimate the complexity of this task.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17452715)

Comment: @Masoud that is not a link only answer. Even if we remove the link from it, one can still google about the principles expressed therein and make their way forward. This looks totally ok.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier links and some descriptions that in my point of view are more like a comment rather than an answer. That's how I feel about this answer but I may as well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [bgRFC technique](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/48/927c2caa6b17cee10000000a421937/frameset.htm). This is a new method of background processing made by SAP.

BgRFC has, in addition to the already existing IN BACKGROUND TASK, the possibility to configure and monitor all calls which run through this method.

You can read more documentation between the different possibilities [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/753088fc00704d0a80e7fbd6803c8adb/7.5.8/en-US/4899b53cee2b73e7e10000000a42189b.html). This is all (of course) depending on your SAP version.

Comment: Yes, bgRFC Inbound scenario can be used. It has also the nicer programming API. But if I understand it correct, you can only use it if you do not need any data back from the remote service call.