# How do I know how many RFC tasks I can create?

Tags: parallel-processing, abap

I'm implementing a report that executes the same code twice, in parallel.

To achieve this, I do the following:

```
  call function 'my_func'
  starting new task 'T1' destination 'NONE'
  calling go_results->receive_results on end of task
    exporting
      it_pernr_tab            = lt_1st_half
      is_selection_parameters = gs_parm.

  call function 'my_func'
  starting new task 'T2' destination 'NONE'
  calling go_results->receive_results on end of task
    exporting
      it_pernr_tab            = lt_2nd_half
      is_selection_parameters = gs_parm.

  wait until go_results->mv_received_results = 2.
```

This will create two new tasks, which will execute just fine.

But I don't make any validations at all, I simply call the task twice because I've decided to.

I don't know if there is enough "room" for two new tasks, nor if there is room for 10 and I could use them better.

And this is precisely my question:

a) can I calculate somehow the max number of tasks that I can create, so that I use parallism to its full? for example, get the number of available work processes?

Comment: I removed the [tag:rfc] tag from your question, as your post has nothing to do with a *Request for Comment*. Please read the description of tags before using them, to make sure you're using tags appropriate to your post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start your asnyc function modules you should call the function module SPBT_INITIALIZE.

Relevant are the parameters group_name, max_pbt_wps and free_pbt_wps

```
CALL FUNCTION 'SPBT_INITIALIZE'
  EXPORTING
    group_name                     = 'YOUR_SERVER_GROUP'
  IMPORTING
    MAX_PBT_WPS                    = lv_max
    free_pbt_wps                   = lv_free
  EXCEPTIONS
    invalid_group_name             = 1
    internal_error                 = 2
    pbt_env_already_initialized    = 3
    currently_no_resources_avail   = 4
    no_pbt_resources_found         = 5
    cant_init_different_pbt_groups = 6
    OTHERS                         = 7.
```

Server Groups are used to avoid that someone will use all available processes at the SAP system. If you do not want to configure 
Server Groups you will use the DEFAULT server group. In addition you should start your async function modules with the name of
your Server Group

```
CALL FUNCTION 'YOUR_ASYNC_FUNCTION' STARTING NEW TASK 'YOUR_TASK_IDENTIFIER'
  DESTINATION IN GROUP 'YOUR_SERVER_GROUP'
```

or if you want to use the Default Group

```
CALL FUNCTION 'YOUR_ASYNC_FUNCTION' STARTING NEW TASK 'YOUR_TASK_IDENTIFIER'
  DESTINATION IN GROUP DEFAULT
```

Here you will find the SAP Documentation for the Server Groups

https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/fa/096e92543b11d1898e0000e8322d00/content.htm?no_cache=true

But anyway, after your call of  SPBT_INITIALIZE you will receive the infos you requested.

lv_max: the maximum available processes for your Server Group

lv_free: available processes at the moment for your Server Group

Answer (score -1):

This question is already discussed and please find link for the topic.

[Parallel Processing with Starting New Task - front end screen timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46426638/parallel-processing-with-starting-new-task-front-end-screen-timeout).

SAP Help document on [Parallel Processing](https://help.sap.com/viewer/7bfe8cdcfbb040dcb6702dada8c3e2f0/7.5.8/en-US/4d909309eba36e73e10000000a15822b.html)

SPBT_INITIALIZE is the FM you are looking for.

Comment: ["please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I thought my answer was detailed enough and directly to the question. SPBT_INITIALIZE returns the number of available work processes.

Comment: I wasn't talking specifically about SPBT_INITIALIZE, I was talking about the **links**. Stack Overflow asks to add context around the **links**. You currently just refer to links without saying anything about what is inside (even if the first link is another question in Stack Overflow). You don't say a word about the words `IN DESTINATION GROUP` that are an essential part of the parallel RFC, SPBT_INITIALIZE being the first part (technically optional, but it answers the question). You don't even say a word about what a RFC group is. Please update your answer/don't add information via comments.